# Simple syntax error null check datatable / gridview asp.net vb 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable, null

I have this code:

```
Dim Result As New DataTable
DataAdapter.Fill(Result)


            'bind data to visible surname/name grid
            If Result.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                NoInputBottom.Text = "No Results. Please widen your search criteria and try again"
                NoInputTop.Text = "No Results. Please widen your search criteria and try again"
            Else
                GV.DataSource = Result
                GV.DataBind()
            End If
```

I have also tried moving the check to the gridview like so:

```
If GV.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                NoInputBottom.Text = "No Options Selected: Please select your search criteria and try again"
                NoInputTop.Text = "No Options Selected: Please select your search criteria and try again"
            End If
```

When I run the code. the noinput labels do not have value, the null check seems to be failing? Please can you tell me how to display a message if the search returned no reults.

Comment: What does the debugger say about `Result.Rows.Count` (if you hover your mouse cursor over it)? This should bring you certainty about the *seems to be failing*, no? I mean you know then if `Count` is indeed not zero (for whatever reason) or if the text in the Labels (or whatever `NoInputBottom` is) gets overwritten later on or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **copy of my comment** to the original question in order to be able to mark the question as answered (thank you Phil).

> What does the debugger say about
>   `Result.Rows.Count` (if you hover your
>   mouse cursor over it)? This should
>   bring you certainty about the *seems to
>   be failing*, no? I mean you know then
>   if `Count` is indeed not zero (for
>   whatever reason) or if the text in the
>   Labels (or whatever `NoInputBottom` is)
>   gets overwritten later on or something
>   similar.